# Java, wait for child process to exit

Tags: java, child-process

Using Java's `ProcessBuilder` I am creating a group of child processes. I can use the `waitFor()` method from the resulting `Process` object to wait for that particular child to exit.

Is it possible to block until **any** child exits, in the manner of the UNIX `wait()` system call?

Answer (score 10):

First step is to represent the work done by each subprocess as a [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), like so:

```
final ProcessBuilder builder = ...;

// for each process you're going to launch
FutureTask task = new FutureTask(new Callable<Integer>() {
  @Override public Integer call() {
    return builder.start().waitFor();
  }
};
```

Now submit all the tasks to an executor:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
for (FutureTask task : tasks) {
  executor.submit(task);
}

// no more tasks are going to be submitted, this will let the executor clean up its threads
executor.shutdown();
```

Now use the excellent [ExecutorCompletionService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) class:

```
ExecutorCompletionService service = new ExecutorCompletionService(executor);
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
  Future<Integer> finishedFuture = service.take();
  System.out.println("Finishing process returned " + finishedFuture.get());
}
```

This loop will iterate once for every completing task as it finishes. The `returnValue` will be the exit code of the child process.

Now, you don't know exactly which process has finished. You could change the Callable to instead of returning an Integer to just return the Process or even better a class of your own representing the output of the process.

Oh and of course if you don't care about waiting for all the tasks, you can just call `take()` once.

Comment: Is there a book which talks about this as a design pattern. It seems very similar to the producer consumer design pattern. However, the Executors and Future are something new to me. Do you have any additional source to read up on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I hat a problem that the `waitFor()` exited too early when I run a `cmd.exe /C start BAT`, I added a `/wait` to the cmd command and it worked as expected. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [CountDownLatch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

> A CountDownLatch is initialized with a
>   given count. The await methods block
>   until the current count reaches zero
>   due to invocations of the countDown()
>   method, after which all waiting
>   threads are released and any
>   subsequent invocations of await return
>   immediately. This is a one-shot
>   phenomenon -- the count cannot be
>   reset. If you need a version that
>   resets the count, consider using a
>   CyclicBarrier.

Answer (score -2):

you have to use some form of IPC to achieve this. If you are allowed to use native libraries and if you work on UNIX/Linux platform try using the same wait() system call by writing a simple JNI wrapper & calling the native method from java code.

If you cannot use native IPC mechanisms use TCP/IP server/client mechanism in which you control the child process exit from the server while the client connects/disconnects to/from the server. When there are no child connections you can exit the server program!

Comment: There's no such thing as a simple JNI wrapper. :)

Comment: The notion that using JNI should be called for here seems distinctly odd, also forgive my ignorance but I didn't know what "some form of IPC" is, your answer did nothing to inform me and even a quick google didn't help. Sorry, I don't very often downvote, but this really doesn't strike me as useful.